# Reason for the difference between arg and atan2

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers

Recently, working with sympy I played and cos(x) being a complex function and discovered that the provided argument function `arg` and the `atan2` function yield different results. This can be easily shown by plotting the results.

```py
import sympy as sp
c = sp.cos(x)
sp.plot(sp.atan2(sp.im(c),sp.re(c)))
sp.plot(sp.arg(c))
```

[image]

Although the difference is just the natural multiple of pi I would expect both functions to return the upper plot. This is also what WolframAlpha yields, see [arg](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg%28cos%28x%29%29) and [atan2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=atan2%28im%28cos%28x%29%29%2Cre%28cos%28x%29%29%29).
Interesting enough if I numerically compute the argument (using the sympy function) I get the expected result:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xv = np.linspace(-10,10,200)
plt.plot(xv,[sp.arg(i) for i in np.cos(xv)])
```

[image]

Can someone please, point me to the difference, and maybe a resonable solution to get equal results?

I'm using sympy 0.7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different plots come from an optimization within sympy. When you plot something, sympy internally uses numpy to evaluate your function. sympy's function `vectorized_lambdify` translates `arg(cos(x))` to its numpy equivalent, `np.angle(np.cos(x))`, and then sympy evaluates that for an appropriate numpy array. So what sympy does is roughly equivalent to

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

xv = np.array(np.linspace(-10,10,200), dtype=np.complex)
plt.plot(xv, np.angle(np.cos(xv)))
```

This reproduces the jumps from -pi to pi. See [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/88cd3abde3c20ca7b53d09f49f67253e63f09327/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py#L118) for the important lines of code within sympy.

The other variant where you use atan is rewritten as

```
np.arctan2(-np.sin(np.real(x))*np.sinh(np.imag(x)), 
            np.cos(np.real(x))*np.cosh(np.imag(x)))
```

which is equivalent to numpy's [definition of angle](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1194), and indeed plotting this also features the jumps. So the more important question, from my perspective, is: Why does a plot of `sp.atan2(..)` look different?

I haven't been able to find a reason for that yet, but I believe that this might exceed the scope of your question anyway?! To answer your question:

- As long as you work with the symbolic version in sympy, everything you do is correct, both *are* equivalent
- If you want to have equal results, the simplest version probably would be to plot modulo 2pi. Alternatively, avoid the `experimental_lambdify` call by plotting something like `lambda val: (expr).subs(x, val)` directly from numpy, or entirely replace lambdify: Execute the following code before running your first example and both plots will look like the upper one:

  ```
  import sympy.plotting.experimental_lambdify
  sympy.plotting.experimental_lambdify.experimental_lambdify = lambda x, exp, **kwargs: vectorize(lambda val: exp.subs(x[0], val))
  ```

  (Note that this version of the snippet will only work for 1d plots.)

Comment: I was more inclined to the upper plot as Wolfram Alpha produces this for both approaches. After all it seems to be just a result of different internal definitions?

Comment: Yes, I got that. My point was to show that the difference originates in the translation of sympy code to numpy code and is only a problem in plots, nowhere else. The last line of my answer was meant as a hint how to produce the same plots with both calls. I'll expand the answer on that.

Comment: I definitely consider this to be a SymPy bug. It should account for these differences when plotting. If you figure out more of what causes this, please make a note on [this SymPy issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8457).

Answer (score 0):

This could be an intended behavior. The argument is typically taken to be from -pi to pi because then the branch cut in the complex plane occurs at the negative real axis instead of the positive real axis

Comment: They definitely should be equal. `arg(x).rewrite(atan2)` gives `atan2(im(x), re(x))`.